# How to make Java function atomic operation, and prevent calculation main thread interruption for handing results from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

This is my calculation function, and my Table of Objects used for the calculation:

```
public class Calculator{

    private Table table = new DefaultTable();

    // calls in UI thread onButtonPressed
    public Result calculate(){
        // do some calculation here with table
        // return Result here
    }

    // calls from Handler.handleMessage() when newtable ready to use
    public void setTable(Table newtable){
        this.table = newtable
    }
}
```

How do I prevent changes to the Table while `Calculate()` is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should synchronize both objects on the same monitor. If those are the only two methods you need to synchronize, you could use `this` as your monitor, which is what the `synchronized` modifier implicitly does:

```
public class Calculator{
    private Table table = new DefaultTable();

    public synchronized Result calculate(){
        // implementation
    }

    public synchronized void setTable(Table newtable){
        this.table = newtable
    }
}
```

For a more fine-grained control, you could just define your own locking object:

```
public class Calculator{
    private final Object monitor = new Object();
    private Table table = new DefaultTable();

    public Result calculate() {
        synchronize (monitor) {
            // implementation
        }
    }

    public void setTable(Table newtable){
        synchronize (monitor) {
            this.table = newtable
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: will it work in my case? The point is both functions run on the Ui thread, but syncronisation works for two different threads.

Comment: If they are both done in the same thread, you shouldn't have a problem to begin with. A thread can only do one thing at a given time.

Comment: One thread can only do one atomic thing at given time. this functions are not calling one by one. We have deal with receiving message from another thread and it can happen any time event when ui thread calculate something.

Comment: If you can receive another message while handling the current one, you must obviously have another thread.

Comment: Any way your solution works fine, but i still do not understand how it works. Thank you Mureinik.